# Functoriality of $\text{Proj }A$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This is a remark from Ulrich Gortz's *Algebraic Geometry* -

> **Functoriality of $\text{Proj }A$ -**
>
> Let $A=\bigoplus_{d\ge0}A_d$ be a graded ring. We can "thin out" $A$ and "change $A_0$" without changing the scheme $\text{Proj }A$. More precisely, fix integers $k,\delta\ge1$ and define a new graded ring $A'$ by $A_0'=\mathbb Z$, $A'_d=0$ for $0<d<k$ and $ A'_d=A_{d\delta}$ for $d\ge k$. $P\mapsto P\cap A'$ defines a bijection $\text{Proj }A\to\text{Proj }A'$. For any homogeneous element $f\in A_+$ we find $f^{k\delta}\in A'$. It is clear that $D_+(f)=D_+(f^{k\delta})$ and it is easy to see that $A_{(f)}=A_{(f^{k\delta})}$. Thus we have an isomorphism $$\text{Proj }A\to\text{Proj }A'$$

**My question :**

So if $R$ is a ring and I wish to study the Proj of the polynomial ring $R[x_0,\cdots,x_n]$ then all I have to do is study Proj of $\mathbb Z[x_0,\cdots,x_n]$? If so then why do we talk of $\text{Proj }R[x_0,\cdots,x_n]$ for an arbitrary ring at all? Can't we just always deal with $\text{Proj }\mathbb Z[x_0,\cdots,x_n]$? What am I missing?

Thank you.

Comment: If you start with graded ring $R[x_0, \ldots, x_n]$, and replace the zeroth gradation with $\mathbb{Z}$, what you get is *not* graded ring $\mathbb{Z}[x_0, \ldots, x_n]$.

Comment: So what is the ring we get? This is all very new and confusing to me :(

Comment: At gradations different than zero, you get the linear combinations of monomials with coefficients _in $R$_, not in $\mathbb{Z}$. The fact that in zeroth gradation the elements are only from $\mathbb{Z}$ is not really relevant.

Comment: Oh I see my mistake. I was thinking of monomials without thinking about their coefficients. It makes sense now. Thank you.

Comment: :) Also, the fact that zeroth gradation is stripped is not really relevant, as you can recover the elements of $R$ by localizing the higher gradations, which is how you construct the $Proj$ as a scheme.